# Duplicate pairs of rows side by side in pandas given certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable, nested-loops

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Col1': ['John 1', 'John 2', 'John 3', 'Kyle 1', 'Kyle 3', 'Kyle 2'],
    'Col2': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'S'],
    'Col3': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Which gives this dataframe in which the numbers in Col1 (column 1) repeat only twice (e.g. John 1 and Kyle 1):

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3
0  John 1    B    1
1  John 2    C    1
2  John 3    E    1
3  Kyle 1    F    1
4  Kyle 3    F    1
5  Kyle 2    S    2
```

I want to make a function that iterates through the names of Col1 and duplicates the row with same number to be beside the original row. My desired output should be something like this:

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 New Col1 New Col2 New Col3
0  John 1    B    1  Kyle 1        F        1
1  John 2    C    1  Kyle 2        S        2
2  John 3    E    1  Kyle 3        F        1
3  Kyle 1    F    1  John 1        B        1
4  Kyle 3    F    1  John 3        E        1
5  Kyle 2    S    2  John 2        C        1
```

Notice how all the values in the original Kyle 1 (row 3) have been duplicated since the '1' matches with 'John 1' in row 0. I have tried using pd.concat within nested for loops but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make self-merge on the numeric suffix of `Col1` and filter out duplicate entries.
The column names are arranged with [`df.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
res = (df.merge(df.add_suffix('_new'), 
                on=df['Col1'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True), how='left')
       .drop('key_0', axis=1))
res = res[res['Col1'] != res['Col1_new']]
print(res)
```

---

```
      Col1 Col2 Col3 Col1_new Col2_new Col3_new
1   John 1    B    1   Kyle 1        F        1
3   John 2    C    1   Kyle 2        S        2
5   John 3    E    1   Kyle 3        F        1
6   Kyle 1    F    1   John 1        B        1
8   Kyle 3    F    1   John 3        E        1
10  Kyle 2    S    2   John 2        C        1
```

Comment: similar logic, note that you can merge with the `add_suffix` variant to avoid renaming after the fact (or use `suffixes`) ;)

Comment: @mozway, good hint, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-[`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on non-equal values after getting the significant digit with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
out = (df.reset_index()
         .merge(df.add_prefix('New '),
                on=df['Col1'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False))
         .loc[lambda d: d['Col1'].ne(d['New Col1'])]
         .set_index('index').reindex(df.index).drop(columns='key_0')
      )
```

Variant with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html), in case there is not directly a unique identifier after each name:

```
out = (df.reset_index()
         .merge(df.add_prefix('New '),
                on=df.groupby(df['Col1'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False))
                     .cumcount())
         .loc[lambda d: d['Col1'].ne(d['New Col1'])]
         .set_index('index').reindex(df.index).drop(columns='key_0')
      )
```

Output:

```
     Col1 Col2 Col3 New Col1 New Col2 New Col3
0  John 1    B    1   Kyle 1        F        1
1  John 2    C    1   Kyle 3        F        1
2  John 3    E    1   Kyle 2        S        2
3  Kyle 1    F    1   John 1        B        1
4  Kyle 3    F    1   John 2        C        1
5  Kyle 2    S    2   John 3        E        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create helper `Series` with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for both pairs, rename columns by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with original `DataFrame`:

```
out = df.merge(df.add_prefix('New '), 
              left_on='Col1', 
              right_on=df['Col1'].replace({'John':'Kyle','Kyle':'John'}, regex=True)) 
print (out)
     Col1 Col2 Col3 New Col1 New Col2 New Col3
0  John 1    B    1   Kyle 1        F        1
1  John 2    C    1   Kyle 2        S        2
2  John 3    E    1   Kyle 3        F        1
3  Kyle 1    F    1   John 1        B        1
4  Kyle 3    F    1   John 3        E        1
5  Kyle 2    S    2   John 2        C        1
```

EDIT:

```
#generate list for dictionary for replace
L = df['Col1'].str.replace('\s+\d+','', regex=True).unique().tolist()
    
out = df.merge(df.add_prefix('New '), 
              left_on='Col1', 
              right_on=df['Col1'].replace({L[0]:L[1], L[1]:L[0]}, regex=True)) 
print (out)
     Col1 Col2 Col3 New Col1 New Col2 New Col3
0  John 1    B    1   Kyle 1        F        1
1  John 2    C    1   Kyle 2        S        2
2  John 3    E    1   Kyle 3        F        1
3  Kyle 1    F    1   John 1        B        1
4  Kyle 3    F    1   John 3        E        1
5  Kyle 2    S    2   John 2        C        1
```

Comment: what if don't know the names for replacement beforehand?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - good point, added solution for generate dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
s = df['Col1'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$')
tmp = df.assign(num=s, TF=s.duplicated())
tmp.merge(tmp.assign(TF=tmp['TF'].eq(False)), on=['num', 'TF'])\
   .drop(['num', 'TF'], axis=1)\
   .rename(lambda x: x[:-2] if '_x' in x else 'New ' + x[:-2], axis=1)
```

output:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    New Col1    New Col2    New Col3
0   John 1  B       1       Kyle 1      F           1
1   John 2  C       1       Kyle 2      S           2
2   John 3  E       1       Kyle 3      F           1
3   Kyle 1  F       1       John 1      B           1
4   Kyle 3  F       1       John 3      E           1
5   Kyle 2  S       2       John 2      C           1
```

**intermediate**

`s` : extract number from Col1

```
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   3
5   2
```

`tmp` : tmp have Col1's number and True, False.

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    num  TF
0   John 1  B       1       1    False
1   John 2  C       1       2    False
2   John 3  E       1       3    False
3   Kyle 1  F       1       1    True
4   Kyle 3  F       1       3    True
5   Kyle 2  S       2       2    True
```

swap True False and merge tmp by tmp